# Is it possible using CSS to define a prescribed list of colour values that can be used in a class?

Tags: css, colors

Is it possible using `CSS` to define a prescribed list of colour values that can be used in a class?

I am working with several content cards which have a top border colour applied. For the design I have a palette of 5 colours.

Is it possible to define these colours as a list in a `CSS` class so that the content cards do not have to have this colour applied via inline style? I would prefer colours to be defined in a class so that `HTML` elements can pick colours from the list in order or randomly from the `CSS` class?

Below is a content-stripped snippit of `HTML` with the in line colour variable applied...

```html
<!-- Content Cards -->
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card-title"></div>
    <div><p></p></div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-card">
        <div class="content-card" style="border-top:2px solid #553ffc;">
            <div class="card-title"><img class="card-icon" src="#" alt="Icon"></div>
            <div><p></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of nth-child, this will add a specific color to all the items added to the cards even if you add 100 cards.

If you only want that color to be applied to a specific container you can use the second example with a more specific class applied to the parent.

I removed some of the html that you use in card to make a more clear example.

```css
.content-card {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: #ededed;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.content-card:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.content-card:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border-top: 1px solid aqua;
}

.content-card:nth-child(5n+3) {
  border-top: 1px solid deepskyblue;
}

.content-card:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border-top: 1px solid deeppink;
}

.content-card:nth-child(5n+5) {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

/* parent container */
.content-card {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.use-border-top .content-card:nth-child(5n+1) {
  border-top-color: green;
}

.use-border-top .content-card:nth-child(5n+2) {
  border-top-color: lime;
}

.use-border-top .content-card:nth-child(5n+3) {
  border-top-color: hotpink;
}

.use-border-top .content-card:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border-top-color: purple;
}

.use-border-top .content-card:nth-child(5n+5) {
  border-top-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card-title"></div>
    <div><p></p></div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-card">
        <div class="content-card">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card-title"></div>
    <div><p></p></div>
    <div class="flex-container flex-card use-border-top">
        <div class="content-card">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            4
        </div>
        <div class="content-card">
            5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a list of colours using css variables, and update them with inline css.

```css
:root {
  --color-1: red;
  --color-2: orange;
  --color-3: yellow;
  --color-4: green;
  --color-5: blue;
}

div {
  background: #eee;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-color: var(--border-color);
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div style="--border-color: var(--color-1);"></div>
<div style="--border-color: var(--color-2);"></div>
<div style="--border-color: var(--color-3);"></div>
<div style="--border-color: var(--color-4);"></div>
<div style="--border-color: var(--color-5);"></div>
```

Comment: why the border-color variable?

Answer (score -1):

Anything you do inline can be done via CSS.

So for the example you gave of;

`<div class="content-card" style="border-top:2px solid #553ffc;">`

You can do this;

CSS:

```
.content-card {
    border-top: 2px solid #553ffc;
}
```

Then strip the inline style;

```
<div class="content-card">
```

Just note though, that this will apply to all elements that contain the class `.content-card`

If you want them to have different colours you can look in to the [:nth-child() selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

or alternatively, you can create classes like so;

```
.content-card.red {
    border-top: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
.content-card.blue {
    border-top: 2px solid #0033ff;
}
```

then on your element you can go;

```
<div class="content-card red">
```

or

```
<div class="content-card blue">
```

Another way is using `:root` in CSS that you can [read more about here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)

**EDIT:** It also appears someone else has given rundown on how to use `:root` css variables

Comment: this don't answer the question in any way.

Comment: I'm looking to define a list of colours in a CSS class so an HTML element will pick from a list of values like #553ffc; #d7fc3f; #fc3f52; #3ffc62;

Comment: @Dejan.S - there's so many different ways one can do this. I'm just rattling off a few.

Comment: No, your first answer gave an example styling the content-card class with a "fixed" border color.

Comment: @Dejan.S I'm not sure you read my answer properly as I gave references and links to resources, but okay!

Comment: I'm referring to your first answer, you know I could see the original answer in the history if you want to say elsewise? What you got now was not that, everything after the line `that contain the class .content-card` was edited and added after my first comment. Not trying to be a asshole here just saying that it actually didn't address the question.

Comment: Haha that's only because I had to edit my response to finish it. The difference between enter and shift enter...  - anyways all good. I think between us all we covered all bases.